# swift pan gesture moving 2 UIViews

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

I need to be able to move 2 x UIViews using a pinch and pan gesture so they act as if the stuck together.

The pinch gesture code works ok. The pan gesture though creates an overlap when you drag the view (see screenshot).

What is needed to correct the overlap that occurs when the view is moved with the pan gesture code i'm currently using? Sorry if this wasn't obvious when I originally posted the question.

Code for the pinch is

```
@IBAction func handlePinch(recognizer : UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        scale = recognizer.scale
        mainImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(mainImageView.transform, scale, scale)
        eraseView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.view.transform, scale, scale)
        recognizer.scale = 1
    }
```

Code for the pan gesture is

```
@IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)

        tx = translation.x; ty = translation.y

        let moveIt = CGPoint(x:recognizer.view!.center.x + tx, y:recognizer.view!.center.y + ty)

        mainImageView.center = moveIt
        eraseView.center = moveIt

        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)

    }
```

[image]

Thanks,
Anthony

Comment: What is needed to correct the overlap that occurs when the view is moved with the pan gesture code i'm currently using.

Comment: If I understand you pic you want to make the view1 and the view 2 stay always on top of each other is that right? if it is have you try view2.frame = view2.frame?

Comment: Sorry, what would setting a frame to the same frame accomplish?

Comment: It would syc the views size and position what I think is what you are trying to do

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. One thin I have noticed is the 2 UIViews have different dimensions. Wondering if that could be causing a problem.

Comment: did you set it in all places where you execute the touch recognition?

Comment: The only 2 gesture recognisers I'm using yes. Strange. The pinch zoom works fine, the 2 views stick when doing that. It's the pan gesture that has issues.